# Taking values from two/multiple matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices:

```
tab
val1 210 201 2001 2020
val2 302 200 2919 3030
val3 839 939 8383 8383

tab2
val1 2.3 3.4
val2 3.4 8.3
val3 7.3 8.3
```

now I first have to take val1 from tab2 and match it with tab's 1st column value and, if matched, multiply val1(tab2) to the corresponding values of val1(tab). How to achieve this logic, any suggestions??
column 1 in tab and tab2 are actually character values, its not row names.
EDIT.

```
1. Take row one first data (val1) and match it with the first column of table one i.e tab. for example, if we are matching val1, then val1 is present in the 1st column 1st row of tab, and it matches.
2. If a match is found then take values of val1 row from tab2 i.e. 2.3 and 3.4 and multiply them with the values of matched row in table 1 i.e tab. meaning multiply first 2.3 to all values i.e. 2.3*210, 2.3*201, 2.3*2001, 2.3*2020. Then take other value and do the same i.e.       3.4*210, 3.4*201, 3.4*2001, 3.4*2020.
3. The result would be two different matrices resulting from each multiplication.
```

Comment: Downvote explanation: These are either dataframes or matrices. If matrices, multiplication is impossible, since they will be character matrices. Learn to post valid R code to create examples. If data.frame , then learn to describe an algorithm ... match what (exactly) to what, and then multiply what (precisely specified) to what? Please demonstrate your abilities to do these by editing the question.

Comment: there is no creation code involved..I am just reading a two different csv file. Offcourse after reading it will be a data.frame but just for some restrictions I cant use data.frame so I converted it to matrices. Down voting doesnt make any sense, as its just a simple question. If I had any further information, I would have provided it..waooo !!!

Comment: Sigh. Downvoting unclear questins makes perfect sense. It's requested infact. If it's a dataframe, then don't call it a 'matrix'. At the very least... Post `dput(tab)` and `dput(tab2)`

Comment: its no more a data.frame in the end. I want to use it as a matrix.

Comment: If only downvoting could be done multiple times. I already explained that it it were a matrix then you could NOT multiply because it would be coerce to character class. Now, please read my earlier comments for meaning and follow my constructive suggestions. Post dput versions and explain what you want in greater specificity.

Comment: Downvoting doesnt make any sense because you should first interact. Unclear questions need discussions as every individual has a different level of understanding. Downvoting reflects wrong question and I am sure my question is not wrong.

Comment: I give up. (I did 'interact'.) I am now voting to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: and what about if I dont understand your answer or your answers are unclear???

Comment: but newaz... if there is a problem of coercion then cant I retrieve values from one matrix and create another matrix after multiplication???

Comment: That last comment is seemed incoherent, ... but what was unclear about the request to post the output from `dput(tab)` and `dput(tab2)`?

Comment: Thanx alot for your valuable suggestion.. in the end I get this close remark just because one person did not understand my question. Common Stack community this was not expected. I am not returning here again. Thanx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-arranging your data into matrices with rownames makes this more convenient, as the row names are not a column, and therefore do not force a mode of character for the numeric data.  Here are how the matrices would look.  I created meaningless column names for this example, in order to show which columns are used for the products in the result.

```
> tab
       a   b    c    d
val1 210 201 2001 2020
val2 302 200 2919 3030
val3 839 939 8383 8383

> tab2
       e   f
val1 2.3 3.4
val2 3.4 8.3
val3 7.3 8.3
```

First, iterate over the intersection of the row names with `sapply`.  This will run one iteration per row name.  Here they all match, but that isn't necessary.  It also isn't necessary that they be in the same order, but it is necessary that the row names be unique.

Then, to create each row, you can use the `outer` function.  `sapply` returns the transpose of what you seem to want, so `t` is used to transpose it back.  Column names could be applied to this result, if desired.

```
result <- t(sapply(intersect(rownames(tab), rownames(tab2)), 
      function(x) outer(as.matrix(tab[x, ]), as.matrix(tab2[x, ])))
    )

result
##        [,1]   [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   [,5]   [,6]    [,7]    [,8]
## val1  483.0  462.3  4602.3  4646.0  714.0  683.4  6803.4  6868.0
## val2 1026.8  680.0  9924.6 10302.0 2506.6 1660.0 24227.7 25149.0
## val3 6124.7 6854.7 61195.9 61195.9 6963.7 7793.7 69578.9 69578.9
```

To assign column names based on the column names of the original set, use `outer` again on the names, this time passing to `paste`.  This ensures that the same order is used for the name computation as was used for the numeric computation.

```
colnames(result) <- outer(colnames(tab), colnames(tab2), FUN=paste, sep='*')
result
##         a*e    b*e     c*e     d*e    a*f    b*f     c*f     d*f
## val1  483.0  462.3  4602.3  4646.0  714.0  683.4  6803.4  6868.0
## val2 1026.8  680.0  9924.6 10302.0 2506.6 1660.0 24227.7 25149.0
## val3 6124.7 6854.7 61195.9 61195.9 6963.7 7793.7 69578.9 69578.9
```

This shows which columns in the inputs create columns in the output.

Comment: As I previously commented, I can not use data.frames. I have to make this work on matrices.
I will try to do this operation on matrices. Thanx for your explanation. I accepted it as an answer because I seriously would like to close this stream.

Comment: Using row names makes this approach work equally well for matrices.  Matrices must have the same mode for all columns, but row names are not in a column, so they do not force the matrix to be mode `character`.  Try the `t(sapply...` code after converting to matrices with `tab <- as.matrix(tab); tab2 <- as.matrix(tab2)`